# OleDbDataAdapter Sporadic Missing Records

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

In my application I'm getting some data out of a local MS Access database file.  I'm puzzled by a sporadic issue where my query for all records of a specific table sometimes returns all the records, and sometimes returns all but the last record.  I'm using the following code

```
string resourceConStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source = C:/FileName.mdb";
OleDbConnection resourceCon = new OleDbConnection(resourceConStr);
OleDbDataAdapter personnelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Personnel", resourceCon);
DataTable personnel = new DataTable();
personnelAdapter.Fill(personnel);
```

When I look at the `personnel` DataTable, sometimes I have the correct # of records and sometimes I'm missing the last record from the Access table.  I haven't been able to find any pattern as to when it works successfully and when it does not.  Any idea what could be the reason for this or suggestions or a way to validate that all records were copied into the DataTable sucessfully?  Thanks

Comment: Do you have the .mdb file open in another application (e.g., in Access) when this problem occurs?

Comment: No, I'm certain that the .mdb file is not open in any other applications unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ... suggestions or a way to validate that all records were copied into the DataTable sucessfully?

One way to do it would be to execute a `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Personnel`, and compare that number (assuming that you get one back) with the number of rows in the `DataTable` after it gets filled.

Comment: Thanks Gord, I'll use this as a  backup check till I find out what the root problem is.